# How do I modify my PATH so that the changes are available in every Terminal session

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I want to add a directory to search my search path. I know I have to modify the `PATH` environment variable. However, I want the change to be permanent, so that it is always in effect, for every Terminal (bash) window I open.

There is an overload of confusing and possibly conflicting information in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

I am using Ubuntu 10.04. Suppose I want to add `/usr/local/foo` to my `PATH`. Which file (`.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.bash_login`, etc...) should I modify and what should the new line(s) look like?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The following command adds a path to your current path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/my/custom/path
```

If you want your setup to execute this command every time, there are a number of places where you can put it. When you login, the following scripts will be executed in this order:

```
/etc/profile      (which starts by loading everything in /etc/profile.d)
~/.profile        (which starts by loading ~/.bashrc if you are running bash)
```

**Notes**

- `~/.profile`  is only loaded if `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login` DO NOT EXIST. Otherwise, at least bash, will load them instead. It is advisable to use `.profile` and not the bash specific scripts. So, if in these attempts you created `.bash_login`, *please delete it now.*
- `~/.bashrc` is only loaded if you are running an interactive session. (something with a prompt where you can actually type something).
- `~/.bashrc` is loaded again and again, *every time you open up a new terminal*. So a new tab in gnome-terminal, a new virtual terminal, etc. So even if you don't login again, `.bashrc` is loaded (and thereby resets its environment) every time you open a new shell.
- Things like byobu should really go into `.profile`, (otherwise it won't work ;-)
- Things like paths should go into `.profile` if you want them to work outside of the interactive sessions. (say when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> in GNOME)

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer if you update it to include the requested export line that should be added to .profile.

Comment: This used to be valid only for console logins (e.g. ssh, or the virtual terminals accessible for Ctrl+Alt+Fx).  I didn't know that /etc/gdm/Xsession sources ~/.profile these days. Neat!

Comment: Yeah, i didn't mention /etc/gdm/Xsession specifically or ~/.Xprofile because there are better ways to make graphical programs launch at start up, which does garantuee that the rest of the environment is already loaded.

Comment: to make this answer more comprehensive please add MattH's comment about sourcing ~/.profile to activate changes without a logoff/on cycle.

Comment: I am running 10.10 and I made sure ~/.bash_profile and ~/bash_login don't exist but my ~/.profile still doesn't seem to be executed when I open the terminal I tested by adding `echo hello` to the bottom of it and its not showing up.

Comment: @JoshuaFlanagan: `export` is not necessary for `PATH`. `PATH` is already an environment variable (as opposed to a shell variable)

Comment: @schwiz: `~/.profile` is not executed on each terminal, it is executed before, when your desktop session starts. The one executed on every terminal is `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 23):

I got it to work by modifying `~/.profile`

It looks like adding ~/bin to my path was a bad example, as there is already code in ~/.profile to do that automatically, if the directory exists.

To add the usr/local/foo directory to my path for every session going forward, I add/edit the following line at the end of my .profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/foo
```

However, to make this take effect, I needed to log out and log back in (simply closing the Terminal window and opening a new one did NOT work).

Comment: Make that `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/foo"`, in case you ever have spaces or other special characters in `$PATH`.

Comment: You can reload the current environment without logging out by typing ". ~/.profile"

Comment: @MattH: no you can't. if you source `~/.profile` in a given terminal, it will be effective for that terminal *only*

Comment: @MestreLion - you are right. I was mentioning it for convenience for the current terminal. Forgot to add that.

Comment: What if I already have something in PATH? Could I append to it like PATHS work in Windows? For example I have `PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"` already.

Answer (score 8):

To reload .profile and take changes effects without logout/login, run:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: this one should be a comment to previous answer

Comment: @Pavlo, or maybe editing that answer and adding it would be more appropriate. Thank You for the comment. And, Bruno, for the answer anyway - it was useful to me.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the path to `/etc/environment`, but be aware that no shell expansions will work; the variable will be set to literally the characters you enter.

Comment: Out of the two methods(adding export command in .profile and adding full path name to PATH in etc/environment), which should be preferred?

Answer (score 4):

Before setting a PATH variable, you need to understand why you are setting the PATH variable. The Path variable is where the system tries to search when you issue some command in your terminal.

Example: `whereis ls` command shows `ls` is there inside `/bin`.
The `ls` command only works if `/bin` is registered in the path variable.

`echo $PATH` gives the currently registered locations. If you want to add another custom location to your path variable there are several ways you can try.

1. ```
   PATH="$PATH:/someLocation"
   ```

   New Path variable is only valid till your terminal closes. No other terminal will be affected. No subprocess can use the new variable.
2. ```
   export PATH="$PATH:/someLocation"
   ```

   New Path variable is valid till your terminal close also all subprocesses will get the new Path variable. No other terminal will get a new variable.
3. ```
   export PATH="$PATH:/someLocation"
   ```

Add this line into the `.bashrc` file present in your home folder. Which is called every time a new bash shell is created. This means you get a new Path variable exported every time a new terminal is opened. But this variable is created for only bash shells. You can use the old Path variable in other shells(ksh, sh, ssh ..).

4. ```
   export PATH="$PATH:/someLocation"
   ```

Add this line into the `.profile` file present in your home folder. Which is called every time you log in. This means you get a new Path variable exported every time your session is created. Which is available everywhere.

If you can't find the `.profile` or `.bashrc` file in your home folder, try to create a new one. Sometimes these files won't be created by the system.

ps: Works in ubuntu. Open to any corrections.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the `.bashrc` file in your `$HOME` directory.

At the very end of this file, add the line:

```
export PATH="$HOME/directory_to_include_in_path/:$PATH"
```

You can also modify the `.profile` file, also in your `$HOME` directory, including the following line:

```
PATH="$HOME/directory_to_include_in_path/:$PATH"
```

This worked for me.

Comment: I don't see what this adds to the other answers which explain more thoroughly.

Comment: This is correct answer if you want change to affect terminal windows. Changing `.profile` has no effect in terminal windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ohmyzsh goto your home directory via the terminal and type

`nano .zshrc`

At the end of the file enter

> export PATH="$HOME/directory_to_include_in_path/:$PATH"

Finally restart your terminal. Worked for me. Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**This is what worked for me**

While setting `JAVA_HOME` variable

In the Terminal, run to create the variable

```
echo 'export JAVA_HOME=“/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home' | sudo tee -a ~/.profile
```

run to add the variable to the Path

```
echo 'export PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH"' | sudo tee -a ~/.profile
```

then

```
source ~/.profile
```

**To see if the variable is set correctly** run

```
vi .profile
```

then `:q` to quit

**To modify the .profile file (In case of a correction)** run

```
sudo vi .profile
```

Press <kbd>I</kbd> to insert.

After modifications press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and `:wq` to save and quit.

Answer (score 0):

First add a shell script to the `/etc/profile.d` directory.

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/app' | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/custom-apps-path.sh > /dev/null
```

The app will then be available via direct invocation the next time you login to the shell.

To make the app instantly available in the current shell, run the following command:

```
source /etc/profile.d/custom-apps-path.sh
```

Answer (score -3):

Going through the basics, I will suggest the following steps:

1. It's recommended to set environment variables in `/etc/environment`
2. Open the file as superuser in an editor as it's a read only file e.g.    gedit:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/environment
   ```
3. System will need password to open it in editable mode. Enter your superuser password and get file opened in a new gedit window.
4. Add new line at the end of file with 
   `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/foo`
5. Save and close the window. It will get command back to terminal.
6. Refresh the environment by running the following command:

   ```
   . /etc/environment
   ```
7. You may check by executing the following command:

   ```
   echo $PATH
   ```

Comment: This is incorrect and will not work. Parameter expansion is not performed in `/etc/environment`