# How to set environmental variable PATH?

Tags: installation, java, environment-variables

I'm using `Ubuntu 10.10` and downloaded `jdk7` from `java.sun.com`. That `jdk` is a compressed file and on extraction there I got all the files and folders of `jdk1.7.0`.

But now if I tries to compile a `java` program than there is an error that `javac` not found.
How could I set `PATH` of `jdk1.7.0\bin` to use `javac` everywhere?

Comment: Can't you find your answer here ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/3744/how-do-i-modify-my-path-so-that-the-changes-are-available-in-every-terminal-sessi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Download the latest version of java from `java.sun.com`
2. Extract the file in your home folder.
3. Run the following commands in terminal

   sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/java/

   sudo mv jdk1.7.0/ /usr/lib/java/
4. Find the file `profile` in `etc` folder of `FileSystem`
5. Edit in editor and write the line

   export PATH=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0/bin:$PATH
6. save it. You might need to `restart` your system to make these change.

You can check the current version using the following command `javac -version`

Answer (score 11):

A better way to install the Sun JDK is like so:

- [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java)

Use `update-alternatives` to do all the heavy lifting for you.

In any case, updating the `PATH` is a very basic command.

- In the default bash shell:

  `export PATH=$PATH:/your/path`
- For csh use:

  `setenv PATH $PATH:/your/path`

**Edit:** Note that this is indeed the instructions for installing Java 6 and not Java 7, which is still - as of now - not available in any official repository or ppa.

Comment: export PATH=$PATH:/your/path would be if he is using bash. For csh use setenv PATH $PATH:/your/path

Comment: True. I added a clarification.

Comment: Is there really a sun-java7-jdk in that repository? I can't find it - maybe because I'm using x64?

Comment: @YuvalA: the `export PATH=$PATH:/your/path` is only working where I'd installed the `jdk1.7.0/bin` but if I place the `java` program elsewhere then how would I be able to compile the `program`?

Comment: @Dan: `setenv PATH $PATH:/your/path` also not working.

Comment: Hmm, turns out Oracle Java 7 isn't going to be available in any Ubuntu repository due to licensing issues. What you have up there is basically how you would install Sun Java 6. However my answer does describe the proper way to install redundant packages and how to use `update-alternatives` to manage symlinks to various versions. In any case, for Java 7 see http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-in.html

Comment: Thanks for info Yuval A. It would help if you would include your latest comment to the answer, since it is quite important part of it (IMHO).

Answer (score 2):

easiest way:

> > sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
> >
> > sudo apt-get update
> >
> > sudo apt-get install -y oracle-jdk7-installer

I don't think you will need to bother setting the path after that.

Answer (score 1):

JAVA CLASSPATH SETTING IN UBUNTU

```
sudo gedit etc/environment
```

enter your password

> PATH=".:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"

(already exist)
just add below two lines (here i am using java6)

> JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386"
>
> CLASSPATH=".:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386/lib"

save that file and restart the system.