# PATH variable to Apache OPENNLP OK but doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, bash, java, environment-variables

yesterday I installed in my Ubuntu AWS 12.04 (Amazon) micro istance OpenNLP and seemed working.

Today when digiting opennlp:command not found

Following suggestions [found here:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3744/how-do-i-modify-my-path-so-that-the-changes-are-available-in-every-terminal-sess?lq=1)
I modified my .bash_profile:

```
export JAVA_CMD=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
export PATH=$PATH:/OPENNLP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH

echo $PATH
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.12/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_40/bin:/OPENNLP_HOME/bin

echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_40

echo $JAVA_CMD
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java
```

What do I have to do next in order to make it work again?

Comment: thanks Alvar for improving the editing. Any ideas to solve the problem? kind regards. Marco

Answer (score 0):

Is `/OPENNLP_HOME/bin` the actual path of of opn_nlp?

What is the output of the below command?

```
echo $OPENNLP_HOME
```

You first need to do:

```
export OPENNLP_HOME="Path TO OpenNLP Folder"
export PATH=$PATH:$OPENNLP_HOME/bin
```