# Path given in Environment variable shows empty after reboot

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, paths, tomcat

I am trying to set environment variable CATALINA_HOME for tomcat server. I used the command

```
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.22
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
```

and

```
export PATH=$PATH:`$CATALINA_HOME`/bin:$JAVA_HOME
```

After executing all these commands when I type `startup.sh` on the terminal my tomcat server started. After reboot when  I type `startup.sh` it is showing

startup.sh: command not found

Also when I tried to check value of environment variable by

`echo $CATALINA_HOME` or `echo $JAVA_HOME`  it is showing a blank line. What should I do now? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3744/how-do-i-modify-my-path-so-that-the-changes-are-available-in-every-terminal-sess)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a directory to my path?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

Comment: In addition to the information in the links provided, note that you should remove the backticks (which denote *command substitution*) from around the `$CATALINA_HOME` variable

Answer (score 1):

To get an environment variable to keep its value after logging out and back in, put the commands in `~/.profile`.