# Can't find or run spotify after `snap install spotify`

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, snap, spotify

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, running this command succeeded:

```
sudo snap install spotify
```

And running it again indicates Spotify is installed. However, running:

```
spotify
```

Gives command not found! Searching in Unity for "spotify" yields no results. What can I do?

Comment: Try `/snap/bin/spotify` to launch it.  You might not have the `/snap/bin` in your path.

Comment: That exists and runs, but nothing happens afterwards.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check your `$PATH` variable by executing in a Terminal:

```
echo $PATH
```

The output should be very similar to this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/share/rvm/bin
```

You have to verify if `/snap/bin` is included in this `$PATH`, otherwise you have to add it manually, here is how to do it: [How do I modify my PATH so that the changes are available in every Terminal session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3744/how-do-i-modify-my-path-so-that-the-changes-are-available-in-every-terminal-sess).

If this doesn't work, try deleting and installing again the snap, the required commands are:

- Execute `sudo snap list` to verify if Spotify is installed.
- Use `sudo snap remove spotify` to delete it.
- Use `sudo snap install spotify` to re-install it again.

After installing it you can run the command `which spotify` to see if it is recognized now.

Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: Thank you!  I was going to mention to OP to add `/snap/bin` to the path as I just tested out spotify and it worked fine.  +1  =)

Comment: Thanks just reinstalled after augmenting the path and it seems to be working now (although takes a solid 15 seconds to load).

Comment: @user126350 Yep, that is one thing I noticed is that it was slow to come up.

Comment: You're welcome to both of you, glad to hear that! :D

Answer (score 8):

The solution is simple.  Log out and log back in again.

Same thing happened to me.  It was the first time I had installed a snap app, and I expect that the `$PATH` variable had changed as per other answers, but the change only takes effect after logging out and logging back in again.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I simply had to open a different Terminal window. For some reason it couldn't find it from the window I'd used to run the snap command.

Comment: `source ~/.profile` should have the same effect if you don't want to open a new terminal.

Comment: @Bprodz , yours is the right answer. Please consider posting it as an answer so I can upvote it. Let me know when you do.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is go to the folder `/snap/spotify/6/usr/bin/` and double-click the file spotify.

This worked to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've added to the menu using `alacarte`, then adding `/snap/bin/spotify` to the music section

Answer (score 0):

I'm on elementary OS FWIW. My paths are correct.

I was able to manually launch the item via @Zzzach...'s answer subbing in the symlink "current" for the version number as his answer must have been early on in the snap spotify install.

So I manually edited the desktop entry at:

```
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/spotify_spotify.desktop
```

To change the exec location from:

```
/snap/spotify
```

To:

```
/snap/spotify/current/usr/bin/spotify %U
```

and then it worked via `snap`. Whether it persists across an update is another story.

I think you could also edit this via the alacarte option too.

Answer (score 0):

On debian 9, I had to add `/snap/bin` to the root PATH manually. Do the following:

In `/etc/login.defs`, you will find the following line:

```
ENV_SUPATH PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Add the path so that it will be:

```
ENV_SUPATH PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

Exit the session, and login again.

Comment: This post is related : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434765/cannot-locate-base-snap-core20-no-such-file-or-directory/1441064#1441064