# Cannot locate base snap core20: No such file or directory

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, snap, ubuntu-core

I have been trying to run firefox but everytime i try to run it through the terminal commands, it shows "cannot locate base snap core20: No such file or diretory". I tried removing and reinstalling firefox as well as snap. Refreshing snap was also of no use. On Removing firefox, terminal shows "error: snap "firefox" has "refresh-snap" change in progress."
Using GUI too, firefox does not turn on.
Please help.

Comment: Let's look at your output: "*"cannot locate base snap core20: No such file or directory"*" Is that true? Is the snap named "core20" installed or not? Use the command `snap list` to find out.

Answer (score 2):

Had to do
sudo snap install core20 --beta
then
sudo snap refresh firefox
finally
sudo snap refresh core20 --stable

... then it worked for me

Comment: A repeat of the already given answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `snap list` to check out your core20. If the last column "Notes" shows "broken" or something like that.
Then `sudo snap remove core20`, then `sudo snap install core20`. 

Then check out `snap list` again.
Also, you'd better check whether other core or apps have "broken" or "disable" in the "Notes" column.
You can use `snap help` to search for what you want. 

This way helped me to repair firefox, hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running in the same problem. [image]

Comment: The way to solve it is still the same as described above.

Comment: no its not it has no effect